# Dotfuscator input string was not in a correct format

Tags: dotfuscator

We own Dotfuscator professional version 3.0.

Today I received an error "input string was not in a correct format".

The serial # is empty.

I have been using this same process to protect the DLLs for many years. First I thought it is Windows 10 issue. So I put the code into a Windows 7 machine. Same result?

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Can you share more information about how someone might be able to replicate this issue? Example code? How you ran the tool?

Comment: I work for the Dotfuscator team at PreEmptive Solutions. Professional Edition version 3.0 is quite old - can you check if you're still seeing this issue with the latest licensed version on [the Dotfuscator Downloads page](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads)? Also note that as a licensed user, you have access to [our support team](https://www.preemptive.com/contact/supportrequestform), who are also able to assist you.

Comment: It is very easy to reproduce. Just click the sample project included in the dotfuscator project. 

Again, it works before without any problem.  Suddenly dotfuscator cannot retrieve the serial number.

Comment: I received an email from the support team which asks me upgrade.  However we use obfuscator in old projects and we don't want to upgrade.  

Can you explain why the serial # is empty? Did you have a server side page to valid the license? If so, can you check whether the page is still working?

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I work on the Dotfuscator team and am answering in that capacity.)

Version 3.0 is over 10 years old at this point and is no longer supported, but you can see if re-registering fixes the problem.
To do this, find the `dotfuscator.dat` file for your version in `C:\ProgramData\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition`. **Back it up**, then delete the original.
You can then run the Dotfuscator user interface, which will create a new DAT file and prompt for the necessary registration information.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem just now. 
I solved it by disabling my network connection.
I think the software is trying to reach a script on PreEmptive website, that return a value not supported by the older version of Dotfuscator.